# OS X: Printer profiles path?

Tags: linux, macos, printer, config-files

I need to know where the "printer profiles" are stored.

I'm not referring to the drivers or any of that, what I'm referring to is when you add a printer, you can define different profiles (IE paper size, orientation, etc) and save the commonly used ones.

If anybody knows where these files are stored, please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.<printername>.plist`